# Set line spacing

Tags: css, line

How can I set line spacing with CSS, like we can set it in MS Word?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Try the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property.

For example, 12px font-size and 4px distant from the bottom and upper lines:

```
line-height: 20px; /* 4px +12px + 4px */
```

Or with `em` units

```
line-height: 1.7em; /* 1em = 12px in this case. 20/12 == 1.666666  */
```

Comment: It don't work in Presto based Opera. I need a workaround... please! :\

Comment: I found I also needed ``display: block;`` for these settings to be effective everywhere, not just top and bottom of paragraph.

Comment: Be careful with that. Inline elements should, probably, be "display: inline-block;"

Comment: Remember that you can't set line-height property's value under '1' or '100%' if you are setting it to an <a> element. If you wanted so, you can set an <p> between your text and your <a>, for example.

Comment: it doesn't work with span because as mentioned by @PatrickT span is not display:block

Comment: @walv, it's not suppose to.Also if you need to use it in a span, it0s preferable to use display: inline-block, instead of display: block.

Answer (score 122):

You can also use a unit-less value, which is the number of lines: `line-height: 2;` is double spaced, `line-height: 1.5;` is one and a half, etc.

Comment: It don't work in Presto based Opera. I need a workaround... please! :\

Comment: @user status: works on my machine. Did you try any of the other answers?

Comment: I mean the the CSS element is recognized, but doesn't affect the rendering output. Tested 12.16 and 12.50. The other answer are basically the same : THEY ALL TELL to use the the line-height element!

Comment: @user Because that's how you do it. I would imagine it's a browser bug or lack of support for that css rule. Should probably be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Sure, asking a workaround is off-topic here... by the way I've seen it affect other browsers brands: it exist when it the setting is set with the DOM or when contenteditable="true" is present.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot set inter-paragraph spacing in CSS using line-height, the spacing between `<p>` blocks.  That instead sets the intra-paragraph line spacing, the space between lines within a `<p>` block.  That is, line-height is the typographer's inter-line leading within the paragraph is controlled by line-height.

I presently do not know of any method in CSS to produce (for example) a 0.15em inter-`<p>` spacing, whether using em or rem variants on any font property.  I suspect it can be done with more complex floats or offsets.  A pity this is necessary in CSS.

Comment: Couldn't you use margins for that for inter-`<p>` spacing?

Comment: In some cases, `margin-top` and/or `margin-bottom` can effectively accomplish what is desired here.

Comment: margin-block-start and margin-block-end are for the spacing before/after a block element, such as <p> tags

Answer (score 10):

Try this property

```
line-height:200%;
```

or

```
line-height:17px;
```

use the increase & decrease  the volume

Comment: @AVD : It don't work in Presto based Opera. I need a workaround... please! :\

Answer (score 10):

If you want condensed lines, you can set same value for `font-size` and `line-height`

**In your CSS file**

```
.condensedlines {              
    font-size:   10pt;
    line-height: 10pt;  /* try also a bit smaller line-height */
}
```

**In your HTML file**

```
<p class="condensedlines">
bla bla bla bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla bla bla bla <br>
</p>
```

**--> Play with [this snippet on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/cpryp1ya/)**

You can also increase `line-height` for fine line spacing control:

```
.mylinespacing {
    font-size:   10pt;
    line-height: 14pt; /* 14 = 10 + 2 above + 2 below */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is what you meant:

```
line-height: size;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `line-height` property; there are many ways to assign line height

Answer (score 1):

Yup, as everyone's saying, `line-height` is the thing.
Any font you are using, a mid-height character (such as a or ■, not going through the upper or lower) should go with the same height-length at `line-height: 0.6` to `0.65`.

```html
<div style="line-height: 0.65; font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace, sans-serif">
aaaaa<br>
aaaaa<br>
aaaaa<br>
aaaaa<br>
aaaaa
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div style="line-height: 0.6; font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace, sans-serif">
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■<br>
■■■■■■■■■■
</div>
<br>
<br>
<strong>BUT</strong>
<br>
<br>
<div style="line-height: 0.65; font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace, sans-serif">
ddd<br>
ƒƒƒ<br>
ggg
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

lineSpacing is used in React Native (or native mobile apps).

For web you can use `letterSpacing` (or `letter-spacing`)