# css text to close hard to read in wordpress

Tags: css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

as you can se the text is to close am

```
#main {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1280px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: Century Gothic,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Also possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845433/css-line-spacing

Answer (score 1):

Use css property `line-height: 14px;` to set height of line between text

```
p {
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: @wazza in your case setting `p` tag as i did will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height`

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/65dnxm73/

Play around with the amount of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the css property **line-height** .
Add this line in the css container of this text:

```
line-height: 24px;
```

change the value and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the font family you used.

Try to add this to your css style:

```
letter-spacing: 2px; //spaces between letters
line-height: 15px; //spaces for each line of words
```

Adjust to your liking.

Comment: Everyone here with the same answers haha

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height`.

```
#main {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1280px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: Century Gothic,sans-serif;
}
```